# Change the list item

Tags: c++, list, foreach, containers, std

Sorry for my English.

Some class:

```
class Kid {
public:
    ...
    string _name;
    std::list<string> _cuteKids;
};
```

Use class:

```
    std::list<Kid> kids;
    kids.push_back(new Kid("Jeck"));
    kids.push_back(new Kid("Anna"));
    kids.push_back(new Kid("Toma"));

    for(auto e: kids) {

         e._cuteKids.push_back("Jeck"); // Many some names...
         [1]
    }
    [2]
```

If you look at the code in the debugger, the list in paragraph 1 **_cuteKids** - have item. But if look at the list in paragraph 2 **_cuteKids** - no have item. Why?

This is just an example, actually I much complicated algorithm, but the bottom line is that after a loop **_cuteKids** becomes empty. As if it is a static variable **(e: kids)**, not a pointer to a variable of **kids**.

Comment: Why does a `Kid` contain a list of "cute kids"? A kid is a kid. One kid doesn't contain other kids. This make no sense. You also have a problem with levels of indirection. Given `std::list<Kid> kids;`, `kids.push_back(new kid("xxx");` can't compile--`new` gives a pointer but you're trying to insert that pointer as the object to which it refers.

Comment: It's strange that you have `std::list<Kid> kids;` and then you add new `kid`s using **`new`**: `kids.push_back(new Kid("Jeck"));`...

Comment: _cuteKids - is a list of children who love child this. The job, it does not change the.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

> ```
> for (auto e: kids) {
>     e._cuteKids.push_back("Jeck"); // Many some names...
> }
> ```

you are doing **copies** of each item in the `kids` container, while iterating the container itself, because you missed a *"simple"* **`&`**.

So, the statement `e._cuteKids.push_back(...);` is operating on a *copy*, **not** on the original item. This local copy *"evaporates"* after each loop iteration, and the original items in the `kids` container are *unaffected*.

You have to properly iterate using **references** (`&`) to the original items, to avoid these local deep copies:

```
for (auto& e : kids) {
    // ... do something on 'e' ...
}
```

---

Note that there is a proposal for *terse range-based `for` loops* (N3994), that may be part of the next iteration of the language (C++17?), to avoid bugs like those in your code:

> [**Range-Based For-Loops: The Next Generation (Revision 1)**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3994.htm)

Using this newly proposed syntax, it can be possible to simply write:

```
for (e : kids) {
    // ... do something on 'e' ...
}
```

without introducing subtle bugs like forgetting the `&`.

Answer (score 4):

`e` is a copy of the list items, so changes to it do not affect the items in the list.

To do what you want, make `e` a reference:

```
for (auto &e : kids)
```